# Proof by induction: you can make any integer that is 35 or more, using a combination of 9s and 5s.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have initially set up an equation in the form of $k=9m+5n$.

$k, m, n$ are all natural numbers and $k\geq35.$

Adding 1 on each side,

$k+1=9m+5n+1$ which is $9(m-1)+5(n+2)$

$k+2=9(m-2)+5(n+4)$

$k+3=9(m-3)+5(n+6)$

and so on.

I definitely see a pattern here but I'm stumped on how to continue without breaking the natural numbers rule.

Comment: See the [Frobenius Coin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: You need to be careful to handle the case $m=0$ for $k+1$, etc.

Comment: @lulu Unclear whether $(0)$ is to be regarded as a natural number.  If not, then the assertion is false, since (for example) $(45)$ can not be expressed as $~9m + 5n ~: m,n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$  If I read the article that you cited correctly, it allows $m,n$ to be any non-negative integers.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

All that is necessary is to demonstrate that the assertion is true for each $k$ in $\{35,36,37,38,39\}$.  This is because you can then add $(5)$ an unlimited number of times to create the ranges:

- $\{35+5, 36+5, 37+5, 38+5, 39+5\}.$
- $\{35+10, 36+10, 37+10, 38+10, 39+10\}.$
- $\cdots$

$35 = 5 \times 7.$ 
$36 = 9 \times 4.$ 
$37 = (9 \times 3) + (2 \times 5).$ 
$38 = (9 \times 2) + (4 \times 5).$ 
$39 = (9 \times 1) + (6 \times 5).$

The one flaw in the above approach is that the creation of the number $(35)$ requires that $(0)$ "9's" be used, and it is arguable whether $(0)$ is to be regarded as a *natural number*.

---

The same flaw pertains to the number $(40)$.  One way of verifying that the flaw exists for each $k$ in $\{35,40\}$ is to consider the following $4$ numbers, for each of the two values of $k$:

- $k - 9.$
- $k - 18.$
- $k - 27.$
- $k - 36. ~: ~k = 40.$

In fact, the flaw also pertains to the number $(36)$, since the combination $4 \times 9$ involves $(0)$ "5's".

Further, the same flaw applies to $k = 45.$

---

Therefore, if $m$ and $n$ are each required to be positive integers, it looks like you must start at $k = 46.$

Then:

- $46 = 36 + 10.$
- $47 = 27 + 20.$
- $48 = 18 + 30.$
- $49 = 9 + 40.$
- $50 = 45 + 5.$